# Handling exceptions in Unity

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, exception

I am working with C# and Unity and putting together a library that I can use in Unity and elsewhere. This makes sense to me as it is for networking and Id like the data handlers and such to generally be the same. For compatibility between Unity and other more up to date C# environments I am putting in extensions where I can like the following:

```
public static class PropertyInfoExtension
{
    public void SetValue(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object obj, object value)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value);
    }
}
```

The error, which was not obvious to me, is that this is calling itself in Unity's version of C#. This code was run on its own thread and this is where I think I am doing something wrong as this should have caused a buffer overflow exception.

I have a registered `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.. I have put in a logging system that wraps to the `UnityEngine.Debug.Log` API. I put in `try {} catch {} blocks` but still Unity would just crash half the time and hang the other half of the time.. I would randomly get an error message and the first time I got the dump from the UnhandledException handler it put me on the track to narrow this down but it feels like I am using C# in Unity improperly but I can not find out what I am supposed to be doing.

EDIT: I guess in one of my revamps of this question I removed explicitly what it is.. What is the right way to get errors out of Unity? Why did this error cause Unity to crash instead of the app to crash and throw its exception? why did the UnhandledExcpetion handler only get called once out of 2 hours of testing?

Those all sum up to how am I supposed to reliably develop a robust error handling system in Unity because apparently what I would normally do in C# is not good enough.

Comment: There is no multithreading in your code, the code you have posted does not describe your issue and your question does not clearly describe the issue either. Not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Why are you even using Reflection inside Unity?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Sorry I guess in a revamp of the question to be more clear I removed the explicit question from my question. Its in there now but I am just looking at how to do reliable error handling in Unity.. because the editor crashing when the app has a stack overflow instead of throwing an exception seems like I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Because the default data serializers are too slow for my use cases... but that is not what this question is about. I want to know why a simple overflow exception crashes the Unity Editor instead of going to the UnhandledException handler.. Why even try {} catch {} blocks around this exception did not seem to work (the app crashed before it caught the exception is my only thought?? I dunno I am new to Unity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments to you question you asked this:

> I am just looking at how to do reliable error handling in Unity.. because the editor crashing when the app has a stack overflow instead of throwing an exception

Unfortunately you cannot handle `StackOverflowException` as of .NET 2.0. Here is quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx)

> In the .NET Framework 1.0 and 1.1, you could catch a StackOverflowException object (for example, to recover from unbounded recursion). Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, you can’t catch a StackOverflowException object with a try/catch block, and the corresponding process is terminated by default. Consequently, you should write your code to detect and prevent a stack overflow.

All you can do is to fix your code. Make sure if you are using recursion, they have a terminating condition. Make sure your setters (in properties) are not calling the getters. That's all the help I can offer.

Comment: So in general I have the right things in place and this exception is just... the exception? I find that mildly amusing.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are having StackOverFlow because you are calling the same method again inside the extension method. So with the following:

```
public static class PropertyInfoExtension
{
    public void SetValue(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object obj, object value)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value);
    }
}
```

you are essentially doing this:

```
public static class PropertyInfoExtension
{
    public void SetValue(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object obj, object value)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value)
        {
            // public void SetValue(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object obj, object value)
            propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value)
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Think about recursive methods that call the same method without terminating point.

```
public int InfiniteRecursiveCausesStackOverFlow(int a)
{
    return InfiniteRecursiveCausesStackOverFlow(a);
}
```

Each method call is recorded in the `Stack`, and infinite method loops like this would make your `Stack` get more memory required than what it can handle, hence called the `StackOverFlow` exception.

To resolve this issue you would need to call the actual business logic inside the method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its not the same method.

Comment: @DávidFlorek Yes it is. It's an [extension method](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/extension-methods), notice that the first parameter has the `this` keyword: this means that this object is the one that had the extension method applied to it and then invoked.

Comment: 2m too late to edit my comment so I deleted it an added this one..  I did not have the actual question in my question.. Sorry about that. But yeah I did say `The error, which was not obvious to me, is that this is calling itself in Unity's version of C#.` in my original question.. I know this was a recursion error now.. I am annoyed it took me 2 hours and random luck in Unity to figure that out.